# The partial map classifier $\eta_{1}: 1 \to 1_{\bot}$ is the subobject classifier

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory

The definition for the partial map classifier $\eta_{b} : b \to b_{\bot}$I was given is that:

let $b$ be a member of a topos, and let $$\{\}_{b} : b \to \Omega^{b}$$ be the exponential adjoint of $$\delta_{b} : b \times b \to \Omega$$ (the exponential adjoint of $f: c \times d \to e$ is the unique arrow $g: c \to e^{d}$ s.t. $ev \circ g \times id_{d}= f$, and $\delta_{b}$ is the character of $\langle id_{b}, id_{b} \rangle : b \to b \times b$), and let $$h:\Omega^{b} \times b \to \Omega$$ be the character of $\langle \{\}_{b}, id_{b} \rangle : b \to \Omega^{b} \times b$, then let $$\hat{h}: \Omega^{b} \to \Omega^{b}$$ be the exponential adjoint of $h$. Finally, let $$f: b_{\bot} \to \Omega^{b}$$ be the equalizer of $id_{\Omega^{b}}$ and $\hat{h}$ then $\{\}_{b} = \hat{h} \circ \{\}_{b}$ so the unique arrow $$\eta_{b}: b \to b_{\bot}$$ s.t. $\{\}_{b} = f \circ \eta_{b}$ is the partial map classifier.

The problem is to prove that $\eta_{1}: 1 \to 1_{\bot}$ is the subobject classifier in the topos. The book I'm using is Goldblatt's Topoi book, which doesn't cover Yoneda's lemma and other useful tools, and perhaps because of that I'm consistently having a lot of trouble with these exercises. I'll greatly appreciate any answer, but perhaps someone can shed a light on this using only what's already been covered so far in his book?

Comment: Just go through it with $b=1$. Many things will degenerate since, e.g., $\Omega^1\cong\Omega$ and $A\times 1\cong A$.

Comment: Have you followed the things in $Set$? It will lead to $B_\perp=\{A\subseteq B:\,A=\{x:A=\{x\}\}\,\}=\{$singletons of $B$ or the empty set$\}$.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the very late reply. I've gotten the answer now. I see that $(\Omega, \pi_{1})$ is a universal element of the functor $\mathscr{C}(-\times 1, \Omega )$, which makes $\{\}$ essentially the True arrow, and then it follows that $\hat{h}$ is basically the identity on $\Omega$ then the only arrow that factors through them is obviously the subobject classifier. Thanks for the replies regardless!

Comment: should I just leave this question as it is then? now that I've already solved it?